# Javascript and jQuery not working on clients server

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my dev site the javascript for maps in the Venue section and the jQuery for the Nav scroll and scroll to top all work fine. http://yogadham.4pixels.co.uk

Upload all the same files to the actual server it's going to sit on and no javascript/jquery works!
http://yogadham.co.uk/xxindex.html

All links are to root so no problem there. I've checked permissions on the .js files. Is this a server issue? Both are Linux. Has anyone had similar issues?

Comment: Start by opening the console and fix all the errors, only when all the javascript errors are fixed will you get it working.

Comment: On the dev site, no errors in the Console, but looking at the console for the 'bad' site, two errors. Not sure how this happens when the files are exactly the same?

Comment: That's probably what you have to find out.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize1 is not defined ` is showing as an error on the xxindex.html page. Also `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`... Please debug your page in a similar setup to the final server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Use Binary mode instead of Ascii mode when transferring files between Windows and Linux via FTP

---

**Long Answer**

It seems to be re-encoding your file (index.html) into a single line, probably upon the FTP upload and therefore the comments are causing section5 to break the JavaScript

```
//remove all comments (temporarily), and confirm if the website works
```

**Edit:** The FTP transfer is the issue: [Reference](http://www.coreftp.com/docs/web1/Ascii_vs_Binary_transfers.htm)

> If you are transferring files from Windows to a Unix based server,
>   Ascii mode will strip out the CR (carriage return) characters found at
>   the end of each line.   You may notice that the file you uploaded is
>   smaller than your local file.   This is completely normal and is
>   nothing to worry about.

In your case, the CR's are causing the file to break.

Answer (score 0):

Files are not the same. Take a look to the HTML generated by both. In production you don't have CR (carriage return) neither LF (line feed) characters :

https://www.diffchecker.com/pks371y6